# Copy grid lines when user copies the grid from webpage and paste it into notepad

Tags: html, css, grid, markup

The user would like to have the grid lines copied with the grid data when he copies from the web page. Is that possible ?

currently the result of copying is something like:

```
name subject
lolo math
fofo history
```

what I want to have is:

```
  |  name | subject |
   ---------------
  |  lolo | math    |
   ---------------
  |  fofo | history |
```

I googled that but I couldn't find a good solution for that, and I'm not experienced in front-end tricks.

Comment: That's impossible to copy something like that to a notepad, notepad doesn't support any borders line or tables, it's text using only.

Comment: Though you can use this https://clipboardjs.com/ so when the user copy you can add your own text into the copied text, and add the borders yourself, though the process might take a while.

Comment: mmm I tried, it copies the whole table but of course it doesn't add any lines to the copied grid. do you think it's impossible to do that with css ?

Comment: as you can tell i directed you to javascript libary. it's obviously impossible with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was a mix of the solutions above use Clipboard.js and parse the copied text:

```
  new Clipboard('.clipboard-btn', {
    text: function (trigger) {
      var originaltext = $(trigger).next('table').closest("#my-tbl").text();
      return addTableLines(originaltext);
    }
  });
```

I'm still writing `addTableLines` because the `split` is not detecting the new lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function changeCopiedText(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get original text from selection
    var originaltext =  window.getSelection();

    // call your function to add the lines to the original text
    var textwithlines = addTableLines(originaltext);

    // add the new text to the clipboard
    if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', textwithlines);
    }
}

// capture the copy event
document.addEventListener('copy', changeCopiedText);
```

But you will have to think about the best way to add the lines in `addTableLines`, according to your needs.

Comment: clipboardData is not working, tried it with event as well, can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `copy` event to your `table`:

```
//Here we assume that your table has an id and it is stored in myTable
document.getElementById(myTable).addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.clipboardData.setData("Text", parseClipboard(e.clipboardData.getData("Text")));
});
```

In the example above `parseClipboard` is assumed to handle your text in the clipboard and convert it as you will. You would want to `split` the text with newline as separator, add your | characters at the start and end of the line for each item (line) and then `join` them with the separator of newline---------------newline